# Open Source PHP Form Management System?

Tags: php, forms

I've found an incredible Form Management System called Formdesk (http://www.formdesk.com). It is very powerful and flexible. However, I would like to know if there is an open source (preferably PHP/MySQL) alternative because there might be cases where I would need to modify the code. Basically, this is the process:

An agent fills one of several forms. He must login so that the user and administrator can know who filled that particular form (these forms are going to be filled on the field using tablet PCs and 3g internet connections).
When the agent fills the form, an email is sent to the client alerting him to approve or reject the form.
After he approves or rejects the form, the form is updated with these new records.
There are approx 3 clients and every client will only be able to see his particular forms when he logs in.

To sum it up:

The Administrator: This will have god's eye view on all forms. He will be able to create, modify, and delete the forms' structure.
Agents: These are the employees who go on site to fill out the form. They must login so everyone will know who filled out the form.
Clients: These are the end clients who can see only their forms. They must also approve or reject the form.

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I found a solution. I used wordpress with a commercial extension known as Gravity Forms ([http://www.gravityforms.com](http://www.gravityforms.com/)/) With a lot of modifications to Wordpress code, I managed to make it look like a Form Management System.

Comment: Did you find any other solution that isn't bind to wordpress ? I'm developping a CMS and I would love to be able to add in it an open source form management system !